# How to get alert when the data is in specific range using listadapter

Tags: listview, bluetooth-lowenergy, listadapter, rssi

im very sorry but i really a beginner in coding but can anyone help me, i am currently developing apps to calculate distance by using bluetooth RSSI. I have made that the app to show the distance when it scan a device. but my problem is i dont know how to make my app give alert or warning when the distance is below specific range. In my case i want to make it give notification or sound to alert when the distance is below 2 meter. below is my code to calculate the distance and i use listview to show the result.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        double dist;
        String action = intent.getAction();

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
        //if conditions for printing the distance.
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            double rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI, Short.MIN_VALUE);

            dist= Math.pow(10,(-69-(rssi))/(20));

            DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            String name = intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_NAME);

            ListAdapter.add(name + " => " + rssi + "dBm\nDistance => " + df2.format(dist) +" metres\n" );
            ListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

[this is how my apps currently is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51XPg.jpg)